# C++ Binary Search Tree implementation does not add every element

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have a simple C++ implementation of a BST. I am only trying to add numbers and to print them out, in order. The problem is that out of the 16 numbers I try to add, I am only able to add 12 (leaving out 32, 15, 14 and 3). The output from my console is shown below:

> Printing the tree before adding numbers:   
> The list is
>   empty    
> The key 32 has already been added. 
> The key 15 has already
>   been added.    
> The key 14 has already been added. 
> The key 3 has
>   already been added.    
> Printing the tree in order after adding
>   numbers:  
> 2 4 21 50 52 64 70    76 80 83 87 100 
> Program ended with
>   exit code: 0

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class BST {

private:

    struct node {
        int data;
        node * left;
        node * right;
    };

    node * root;

    void addLeafPrivate(int data, node * n);
    void printInOrderPrivate(node *);


public:

    BST();
    node * createLeaf(int data);
    void addLeaf(int data);
    void printInOrder();


};

int main() {

    int TreeKeys[16]= {50, 76, 21, 4, 32, 64, 15, 52, 14, 100, 83, 2, 3, 70, 87, 80};
    BST bst;

    cout << "Printing the tree before adding numbers: \n";
    bst.printInOrder();

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        bst.addLeaf(TreeKeys[i]);
    }

    cout << "Printing the tree in order after adding numbers: \n";

    bst.printInOrder();

    return 0;
}

BST::BST() {root = NULL;}

BST::node * BST::createLeaf(int data) {

    node * n = new node;

    n->data = data;
    n->right = NULL;
    n->left = NULL;


    return n;

}

void BST::addLeaf(int data) {
    addLeafPrivate(data, root);
}


void BST::addLeafPrivate(int data, node * n) {

    if (root == NULL) {
        root = createLeaf(data);
    }

    else if (data < n->data) { // add recursively on left left side.
            if (n->left != NULL){
            addLeafPrivate(data, n->left);
            }
            else { // if left is empty
                n->left = createLeaf(data);
            }
        }

        else if (data > root->data) { // add recursively on right left side.
            if (n->right != NULL) {
                addLeafPrivate(data, n->right);
            }
            else { // right is empty
                n->right = createLeaf(data);
            }


        }

    else {
        cout << "The key " << data << " has already been added.\n";
    }
}

void BST::printInOrder() {

    printInOrderPrivate(root);

}

void BST::printInOrderPrivate(node * n) {

    if (n != NULL) {

        if (n->left != NULL) {
            printInOrderPrivate(n->left);
        }
        cout << n->data << " ";

        if (n->right != NULL) {
            printInOrderPrivate(n->right);
        }


    }

    else {
        cout << "The list is empty\n";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
else if (data > root->data) { // add recursively on right left side.
```

should be

```
else if (data > n->data) { // add recursively on right left side.
```

The problems start when you come to `32`. Since `21` is already left of `50`, your algorithm thinks it's already inserted `32`, when you do `root->data` instead of the correct `n->data`, instead of comparing the `data` values and throwing an exception.

So: Check right and left for `null`, compare if `data` is greater or less AND check for equality. Doing so lets you more easily find bugs like this.

Comment: I'm not sure if the original code was pasted into SO badly, but the bug was immediately obvious to me the instant the code was formatted correctly.  If the source code wasn't formatted correctly for the OP, that may have contributed to the difficulty finding the issue.

Comment: I agree. I, however,  "debugged" it by creating the tree in my mind by following the code. But yes, it is quite obvious when the code is formatted properly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation. I will try to be more careful next time (and to format my code correctly), but I appreciate your help!!